# Limit JSON Column to specific Objects by using Check Constraints

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

We are using Oracle 12.2 and have the following table structure:

```
create table myData
(
    id number,
    json_data varchar2(4000),
    CONSTRAINT checkJson    CHECK (json_data IS JSON STRICT WITH UNIQUE KEYS),
    CONSTRAINT checkJson_F1 CHECK (json_exists(json_data, '$.FIELD1')),
    CONSTRAINT checkJson_F2 CHECK (json_exists(json_data, '$.FIELD2'))
);
```

We use constraints(checkJson_F1 , checkJson_F2) to ensure that inserts/updates are only possible when FIELD1 and FIELD2 are existing:

```
insert into myData(id, json_data) values(1, '{"FIELD1" : "abc", "FIELD2" : "def"}'); -- OK
insert into myData(id, json_data) values(2, '{"FIELD1" : "abc"}'); -- Error
```

Is there a way to check for non existing objects, for example i want to limit that the following insert generates an error:

```
insert into myData(id, json_data) values(1, '{"FIELD1" : "abc", "FIELD2" : "def", "FIELD3" : "def"}');
```

In other words: i want a check constraint where i can limit the objects which can be stored in the JSON-column. My PseudoCode would look like:

```
CONSTRAINT checkJson_FX CHECK (json_getObjects(json_data, '$.*') in ("FIELD1", "FIELD2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table myData (
  id number,
  json_data varchar2(4000),
  CONSTRAINT checkJson    CHECK (json_data IS JSON STRICT WITH UNIQUE KEYS),
  CONSTRAINT checkJson_F1 CHECK (
    json_exists(json_data, '$?(@.size() == 2 && exists(@.FIELD1) && exists(@.FIELD2))')
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, it looks that the .size() Function is only working in higher versions (19c for example). In 12.2 i get null when i call this function: 
SELECT json_value('{"FIELD1" : "abc", "FIELD2" : "def"}','$.size()')  FROM dual;